# How to unescape unicode string in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a Unicode string from a text file such that. And I want to display the real character.

For example:

```
\u8ba1\u7b97\u673a\u2022\u7f51\u7edc\u2022\u6280\u672f\u7c7b
```

When read this string from text file, using `StreamReader.ReadToLine()`, it escape the `\` to `'\\'` such as `"\\u8ba1"`, which is not wanted.

It will display the Unicode string same as from text. Which I want is to display the real character.

1. How can change the `"\\u8ba1"` to `"\u8ba1"` in the result string.
2. Or should use another Reader to read the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why when I read from an XML document do I get \r\r\n\n etc etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980968/why-when-i-read-from-an-xml-document-do-i-get-r-r-n-n-etc-etc)

Comment: You could provide encoding in the StreamReader constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in a .NET string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string)

Comment: See my answer to this problem here: [Evaluate escaped string in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629020/evaluate-escaped-string

Answer (score 26):

If you have a string like

```
var input1 = "\u8ba1\u7b97\u673a\u2022\u7f51\u7edc\u2022\u6280\u672f\u7c7b";

// input1 == "计算机•网络•技术类"
```

you don't need to unescape anything. It's just the string literal that contains the escape sequences, not the string itself.

---

If you have a string like

```
var input2 = @"\u8ba1\u7b97\u673a\u2022\u7f51\u7edc\u2022\u6280\u672f\u7c7b";
```

you can unescape it using the following regex:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
    input2,
    @"\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})",
    m => char.ToString(
        (char)ushort.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));

// result == "计算机•网络•技术类"
```

Comment: One can also use the static `Regex.Unescape`.

Comment: No, Regex.Unescape is only for Regex characters

Comment: Please don't use Regex.Unescape. It will do the job for the unicode escaped characters, but it will potentially also unescape other text that contains Regex-related keywords.

Answer (score 6):

This question came out in the first result when googling, but I thought there should be a simpler way... this is what I ended up using:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//...

var str = "Ingl\\u00e9s";
var converted = Regex.Unescape(str);
Console.WriteLine($"{converted} {str != converted}"); // Inglés True
```

Comment: UrlDecode does nothing for `\u00e9`, because it is already the real character. If you apply this to the question it would be  `string x = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Ingl\\u00e9s");` which does not do anything.

Comment: @Silvermind good catch. Edited the answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing Newtosoft.JSON the solution is quite simple:

```
var s = @"\u8ba1\u7b97\u673a\u2022\u7f51\u7edc\u2022\u6280\u672f\u7c7b";
s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"" + s + "\"");
```